# Mongodb: writing filter query to search specific data using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm writing a script using pymongo where i have a set data pattern in dictionary form. example

```
{'id': 'xxx', 'data': {'date1':['data1','data2'], 'date2': ['data1', 'data2'],.....}}
{'id': 'yyy', 'data': {'date1':['data1','data2'], 'date2': ['data1', 'data2'],.....}}
{'id': 'zzz', 'data': {'date1':['data1','data2'], 'date2': ['data1', 'data2'],.....}}
...
```

i want to filter data by providing 'id' and 'date'. to do that task i used pymongo query set like

```py
value = mycol.find_one({'id': 'xxxx'})
```

once i get single dictionary  of id = 'xxx' then again searching for date in it which is working but i want to do it in more optimized way.
how can i write query for that?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can search for multiple fields in a single query.

```
doc = mycol.find_one({"_id" : 'xxx', 'data.date1' : 'date'})
```

The query will automatically search for a doc with `id` of `xxx` **and** a `data.date1` value of `date`. If the field is an array MongoDB knows to search inside the array for the field value you are looking for.

Full syntax for `find` is at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/

Pymongo API for `find` is at https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find